# how to create project for wp8/winrt

Tags: cocos2d-x

in create_project.py

```
# Create cross-platform cocos2d-x project

# define global variables
PLATFORMS = {
    "cpp" : ["ios", "android", "win32", "mac", "linux"],

}
```

I can not find out the parameter to create the cocos2dx project for wp8/winrt.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My create_project.py file looks exactly like this: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/2790/create_project.py (I use version 2.2.1). If you specify `cpp` in the parameters, it creates `wind32` and `winrt` in `platforms_list`:

```
if ("cpp" == context["language"]):
        context["src_project_name"] = "HelloCpp"
        context["src_package_name"] = "org.cocos2dx.hellocpp"
        context["src_project_path"] = os.getcwd() + "/../../template/multi-platform-cpp"
        platforms_list = ["ios",
                          "android",
                          "win32",
                          "winrt",
                          "wp8",
                          "mac",
                          "blackberry",
                          "linux",
                          "marmalade"]
```

Then it uses those values here:

```
for platform in platforms_list:
    processPlatformProjects(platform)
```

Project template is supposed to be created in your project path.

Comment: I am using 3.0alpha0-pre, there is no option for winrt and wp8

Comment: @gthacoder when i run create_project.py I got this.. 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../cocos2d-x-2.2.1/tools/project-creator/create_project.py", line 191, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(context["src_project_path"], context["dst_project_path"], True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 168, in copytree
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/../../template/multi-platform-cpp'

Comment: should we be using winrt project or wp8 project to make a game for windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x 3.0 doesnt support winrt or windows phone. You would have to use 2.2.3 for it and cpp as the language.

For winrt you would use the proj.winrt folder and proj.wp8 or proj.wp8-XAML for making games for wp8.